# How to retrieve single image URL from Meteor CollectionFS?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars, collectionfs

I need to retrieve an URL to an image from CollectionFS. Image IDs are referenced in posts so first off I find find an Image that belongs to a certain post like this:

Template:

```
{{#each drafts}}
    <img src='{{images pictures.[0]}}'>
{{/each}}
```

Helper:

```
images: function (id) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log((Images.findOne()));
    return Images.findOne({_id:id});
}
```

According to CollectionFS examples you get the URL to image by using {{image.url}}, but in my case {{images.url pictures.[0]}} does not work and return a handlebars error to console. What is the correct way in my case to access images.url data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no reason to access the `URL` using a `Template.helper`, FSCollections comes with a handily [UI-helpers](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#url) , and you can use it like this.

```
{{#each drafts}}
    URL: {{this.url}}
    <img src='{{this.url}}'>
{{/each}}
```

Just be sure that you have the correct download allow

```
Images.allow({
 download:function(){return true;}
})
```

**FYI** if you are using `findOne` there is not possible use `{{#each}}` you should use `{{#with}}` since the each helpers only accepts arrays and objects

Check [Understanding SpaceBars](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/)

Answer (score 2):

In helper you can call like this:

```
var image = Images.findOne({_id:id});
return image.url();
```